# Working with Multiple Segues | How to use Cell data to perform specific Segues

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, segue

I am displaying data in a collection view, I know how to pass the data on with prepareForSegue function but am trying to have the app determine which segue to use depending on the cell property data. (Each segue goes to a different view controller to display relevant information.)

For e.g.

If the cell.type is equal to `"1"` then perform `segueOne` if it is of type `"2"` then perform `segueTwo`.

I was trying to do something like this;

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    if cell[indexPath].type = "1" {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage1", sender: self)
    } else if self.cell[indexPath].type = "2" {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage2", sender: self)
    } else { println("error when selecting cell to segue") }

}
```

However with this I get an error;

> 'CollectionViewCell' does not have a member named Subscript

Has anybody got any ideas ?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @QED Yes, I returned back to this question today and accepted an answer. I did modify the code. Check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the items in your collection view can be re-arranged (or might be some time in the future), the `indexPath` will not be sufficient to give you the information which cell was selected. Thus, IMO your idea to give the cell a property is a feasible one.

The easiest "quick and dirty" way is to simply hardcode the segue identifier string into your cell. This is not the best design because you are introducing dependencies between app elements that should know of each other.

```
class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    var segue = "DefaultSegue"
}
```

Now calling the appropriate segue is really easy in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`...

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(cell.segue, sender:cell)
```

It would of course be preferable to use an `enum`. Safer, more readable and better maintainable.

```
enum Segue : String {
   case ToInfo  = "SegueToInfo"
   case ToLogin = "SegueToLogin"
   // etc.
}
```

The ivar for `MyCell` would now be `var : Segue = SomeDefaultValue` and you can call it the same way.

---

BTW: Regarding your original question please note the following: as has been pointed out, you cannot subscript a cell. (`UICollectionViewCell` is not a `Dictionary`, so `cell["key"]` does not make sense.) Also, I am not a fan of dequeueing the cell in more than one place - instead you could call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` or do the work in that method in the first place, as I have suggested.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, the correct call I found was        `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.array[indexPath.row].segue, sender: cell)` in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. PS: I am unsure is there was confusion with my question, but I was using an array to display the data. Anyways thank you I have it working

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to index into a `UICollectionViewCell`, but of course that class is not an array, so you can't 'subscript' it.

My suggestion is to refactor your code. Whatever data you're storing in your cell you can presumably get from your data model, because that's where it originally came from. You are probably putting that in your cell in `cellForIndexPath`.

If that is the case, then there is no reason you can't get the same data from the same place in your `func ... shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath ... -> Bool`. I'd suggest doing it there. Your cell should only contain the data it needs to properly render itself to the screen.

See if that helps.